# ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(:another_db) is not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord, connection-pooling

Two databases are defined in database.yml, the `production` (default) and `slave`.

Using console to execute `ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(:slave)` and then `User.count`, the query is still executed on the `production`.

Why does this happen and how the query be made to run on `slave`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a method on User to toggle the connection

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.connect_to_slave
    establish_connection :slave
  end
  def self.connect_to_prod
    establish_connection :production
  end
end
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it's not possible in our case to do model specific delegation of reads to the slave. We are looking for a way to control the used database for all models on a controller action level. Is it possible?

Comment: Do you have any other declarations of establish_connection? One thing that could be blocking you is if User has it's own establish_connection method elsewhere which would not be overwritten by ActiveRecord::Base

Comment: Thanks. No other calls to establish_connection. We'll try your method. Does that chain properly? Ie. If we do User.connect_to_slave and then User.includes(:comments) and then at some point user.comments.post (which will generate a query), will this new query properly propagated through the `:slave`?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know how it will chain. Since it's a method called on User, I *believe* it will use slave, but I wouldn't know without testing.